# Integral upper bound

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A$ be a measurable set and $f$ an integrable function onto $[0,100]$ for example. Having knowledge of the value $\frac{\int_A f d\mu}{\mu(A)}$ (which in some sense is the average value of $f$) I would like to have a good upper bound for $\int_A \frac{1}{1+f} d\mu$. Let me explain with some details.

We know the inequality $ \int_A {|g|} d\mu \leq |g|_{\infty} \mu(A) $. So, using this to $\int_A \frac{1}{1+f} d\mu$ we can say that $\int_A \frac{1}{1+f} d\mu \leq \int_A \frac{1}{1+0} d\mu=\mu(A)$.  However in some cases, this is not so good. I will give an example.

For $g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$, we have that $\int_0^{100} \frac{1}{1+x} d\mu \leq \int_0^{100} \frac{1}{1+0} d\mu=100$ which is a pretty bad bound approximating the integral considering the actual value of the integral is $\log{101}$.

However, by substituting the function $f(x)=x$ with its average value $\frac{1}{100} \int_0^{100} x d\mu=50$ we get that $\int_0^{100} \frac{1}{1+50} d\mu =\frac{100}{51}$ which is in fact a much closer value to the actual integral (but of course is not an upper bound).

My question is, is there a way using knowledge of $\frac{\int_A f d\mu}{\mu(A)}$ to get a rigorous much closer upper bound to $\int_A \frac{1}{1+f} d\mu$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the range of $f$ is contained in $[0,100]$ "for example". The weasel words make it hard to know the exact hypotheses. I'm going to assume $f\ge0$.

One thing you could do is this:

Say $$\frac1{\mu(A)}\int_A f=L.$$

Adding the fractions shows that $$\left|\frac1{1+f}-\frac1{1+L}\right|
\le\frac{|f-L|}{1+L}.$$Hence $$\frac1{1+f}\le\frac1{1+L}\left(1+|f-L|\right),$$
so $$\frac1{\mu(A)}\int_A\frac1{1+f}\le\frac1{1+L}\left(1+\frac1{\mu(A)}\int_A|f-L|\right).$$If $f$ is close to constant on $A$ that gives a bound very close to $1/(1+L)$, about as good as you'd expect.

EDIT: Come to think of it, Jensen's inequality (with the convexity of the function $1/(1+t)$ shows that $$\frac1{\mu(A)}\int_A\frac1{1+f}\ge\frac1{1+L},$$
so a bound better than $1/(1+L)$ is impossible.

Comment: Thank you. This looks great. And yes, I was assuming f is non negative, the "for example" was simply the 100 part. Sorry for the lack of clear explanation.

Comment: @Clayton That's not going further, that's a step backwards. (As I noticed when I took exactly the same step before posting.) You end up with an upper bound greater than $1$. But, as the OP pointed out, the upper bound $1$ is trivial, just because $1/(1+f)\le 1$.

Comment: Added a tidbit.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: You are correct! My apologies 0.o haha, I wasn't thinking, just 'mathing'